# Corrupted JS, CSS and PHP files

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery, corrupt-data

I know that this is a really dumb question but after I reformatted my flash drive ( it says it's corrupted and needs to be formatted so I did it ) and used a recovery software to recover the files that are in it, I got all my files back.

However, Some of my `php`, `css` and `js` files' contents were transformed into something like this:

```
494e 4458 2800 0900 064b 3605 0000 0000
1a00 0000 0000 0000 2800 0000 2008 0000
e80f 0000 0000 0000 0200 6900 0000 0100
0000 0000 7400 cd01 0000 0000 0000 0000
bea9 0000 0000 0100 7000 5a00 0000 0000
f915 0000 0000 0100 a09f 1e22 036b cd01
```

Is there anyway to recover my files back as good as it was before?

Comment: I face this issue also, and I lost everything :(

Comment: Please retag your question appropriately. It is not about actually PHP/HTML/CSS but about restoring lost data.

Comment: Never ever EVER use USB drives for storing the only copy of important data. They're a means of transporting backup copies from A to B.